# How to Write Custom HTML Document to file

Tags: vb.net, file-io

The basic question is: What is the best way to write data from a hierarchical set of objects to a file? The highest order parent has 1000's of children all with children (DOM style). Trying to traverse the tree and creating one big string which is then written to a file is throwing an out-of-memory exception while creating the string.

***Details***
I've created a set of classes that make up an *HTML* document.
There was control that I needed that the pre-packaged `HtmlElement` and `HtmlDocument` didn't give. The *Document Object Model* is maintained throughout, with some similar methods and properties and such.
I'm using the custom classes to create a very large *HTML* document. When I say large, I mean on the order of over 2000 printed pages. It's doubtful that they will all be printed, but some will be.

My base `HTMLElement` object, from which all other objects are derived, contains an `OuterHTML` property which, as expected, gets the full *HTML* of the calling object and the *HTML* of all child elements.
After the code which generates the report runs, I have my *HTMLDocument* object containing the entire report which needs to be written to a file. Here is where I keep running into problems.

If I call `OuterHTML` on the `HTMLDocument` object, I get an *out of memory* exception. 
Other reports have saved fine, but this is by far the largest report I've thrown at my `HTMLElement` object. My assumption is that the property call is generating too much text.

I am basically just creating a new *.HTML* file, opening it for reading, and writing in all of the text. Like:

```
File.WriteAllText(FileName, HtmlDoc.OuterHTML)
```

So the question is: what is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left this question up for a couple of days, hoping for some suggestions, but no luck. So after spending that time trying to come up with some solution, I finally came up with one that is, I think, pretty decent.

In my `HTMLDocument.SaveDocument()` routine, I created a `FileStream` and a `StreamWriter` object. And since the document is a tree structure, I created a recursive routine which takes the `StreamWriter` and the tag collection as arguments.

```
Public Sub SaveDocument(ByVal FileName As String, Optional ByVal IncludeLineBreaks As Boolean = False)
    If Len(FileName) > 0 Then
        'Save the document
        Dim fs As FileStream
        Dim s As StreamWriter
        Dim LineBreak As String = IIf(IncludeLineBreaks, vbCrLf, "").ToString()

        Try
            fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
            s = New StreamWriter(fs)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Cannot save the HTML document." & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Save HTML Dcoument Error")
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Try
            With s
                .BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)

                'begin the html document
                .Write(Me.DocType.OuterHTML & LineBreak)
                .BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)

                Me.RecursiveDocumentSave(s, Me, LineBreak)

                .Close()
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error saving the HTML document." & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Save HTML Dcoument Error")
        End Try

        s = Nothing
        fs = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RecursiveDocumentSave(ByRef s As StreamWriter, ByRef tag As HTMLTag, ByVal LineBreak As String)
    s.Write(tag.OpenTagText & LineBreak)
    s.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)

    For Each t As HTMLTag In tag.Tags.Items
        If t.TagType = "TEXT" Then
            s.Write(t.Text & LineBreak)
            s.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
        Else
            Me.RecursiveDocumentSave(s, t, LineBreak)
        End If
    Next

    s.Write(tag.CloseTagText & LineBreak)
    s.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
End Sub
```

The `OpenTagText` property gracefully handles tags like `<br />` and `<img />` that are self closing. These tags will not have children so the `for` loop will be skipped.